# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ns' of undefined in jquery-flip

Tags: jquery, flipboard

I'm implementing image flip like `flipboard app` using [jquery flip pulgin](http://amegan.github.io/jquery-flip/).

My html is:

```
 <div id="flipRoot">
   <div class="flipContent">
     <img src="{{ asset('layout/images/img3.jpg') }}" alt=""> 
   </div>
 <div class="flipContent">
     <img src="{{ asset('layout/images/img3.jpg') }}" alt=""> 
   </div>
 <div class="flipContent">
     <img src="{{ asset('layout/images/img3.jpg') }}" alt=""> 
   </div>
</div>
```

and js :

```
 $("#flipRoot").flip({
            forwardDir: "ltor",
            height: "340px",
            showpager: true,
            loop: true
});
```

I'm getting **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ns' of undefined**  error.
Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: is flipRoot attached to DOM when you call `$("#flipRoot").flip` ?

Comment: Sorry.I didn't get you.

Comment: javascript can be executed before the html gets loaded. try doing `alert($("#flipRoot"))` before calling .flip to be sure.

Comment: alert($("#flipRoot")) is giving object.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Q9CPe/. jQuery version?

Comment: jquery version 1.10.1

Comment: It is jquery version problem in jquery 1.8.3 works fine.